# Подключение логики twig к шаблону

Tags: php, symfony2, twig

Всем добрый день, у меня есть index.html.twig в котором происходит вся логика приложения, но сейчас потребовалось вынести весь функционал в отдельный файл и в индексе оставить только хтмл верстку. Может кто-то мне подскажет как это возможно реализовать? Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: У вас не должно быть никакой логики приложения в шаблонах.

Comment: Ну предыдущий разработчик написал именно так, в логику встроено очень много твиговских элементов. Так что нужно вынести все в отдельный файл твиг.

Comment: Выносите из твига вообще (хотя я не понимаю, как логику туда вообще можно было поместить)

Comment: Я если честно тоже не особо понимаю зачем это было сделано, но все работает:) Сейчас я уже разделил на 2 отдельных файла, но заставить их вместе работать никак не получается(

Comment: я думаю без примера этого шаблона не обойтись, иначе вы вам помочь не сможем